# VBA code to determine if current time is within a time range

Tags: vba

I need to determine if the current time falls between a time range in VBA. I have seen many ways to do this and none have worked. I can get the current time without a problem.

```
lbShiftNum.Caption = Time()
```

or

```
Dim sTime As String
sTime = Time()
lbShiftNum.Caption = sTime
```

I have worked with variations of the following code to determine if the time falls within a range. I know the examples I am giving may have issues. These are examples I found doing a web search.

```
Dim sTime As String
sTime = Time()
If sTime > #1:00:00 PM# And sTime < #6:00:00 PM# Then ....
```

or

```
If Time > TimeValue("00:01:00") And Time < TimeValue("06:50:00") Then ....
```

Comment: `without a problem` - but there is a problem. You are converting a date to string. Is that in fact what you found doing your web search?

Comment: Simpler to `if hour(time) > 13 and hour(time) < 18` ?

Comment: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=8259

Comment: Yes those snippets of code are from web searchs.

Comment: "if hour(time) > 13 and hour(time) < 18 " does not work

Comment: It should work fine.  What is the value if you print `hour(time)` ?

Comment: Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer) 
lbShiftNum.Caption = Hour(Time)
End Sub returns 12 which it currently is.

Comment: Then `if hour(time) > 13 and hour(time) < 18` is going to be `false`.

Comment: I know. I adjusted my code

Comment: If Hour(Time) > 11 Then lbShiftNum.Caption = "SHIFT 1" works like it should based on my current time.

Comment: Your code works Alex K.